# discord.jsでグローバルチャットを作りたい

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Node.jsのdiscord.jsにてグローバルチャット（A鯖のBチャンネルで「あ」と言ったらC鯖のDチャンネルで「あ」と出てくるようなことをしたいのですが、うまくできません。
何が間違っているか教えてください。

作ってみたコード

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.author.bot){
        return;
   }
    if (message.channel.name === 'd-global-chat') {
        let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
        client.channels.find("name","d-global-chat").send(args.join(" "));
    }
});
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　「うまくできません」ということですが、どのようにうまくいっていないのかを追記して頂くと状況が分かりやすくなり、回答が集まりやすくなります（何も応答がないのか、エラーが出るのか、など）。また、お使いの node.js や discord.js などのバージョン情報がもし分かれば追記して頂けると、回答者が問題を再現しやすくなって回答が集まりやすくなります。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/162794

Answer (score 0):

かっこ悪いやり方になるのですが、サーバー、チャンネルのIDを指定するといいかと。
(後、ボットは各鯖に入れておかないとだめですよ。)

```
if(message.channel.name === "A鯖のチャンネル名"){
    let message2 = message.content.toString();
    return client.guilds.get("A鯖ID").channels.get("A鯖チャンネルID").send(`${message.author.username}＜` + `${message2}`);
}
if(message.channel.name === "B鯖のチャンネル名"){
    return client.guilds.get("B鯖の鯖ID").channels.get("B鯖のチャンネルID").send(`${message.author.username}＜` + `${message}`);
}
```

申し訳ない...三つ以上の鯖を結ぶ場合は解らないです...